# How to keep a user signed in on an Electron app using Auth0?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, electron, auth0

There seem to be no complete explanations of how to do this, or even enough fragments for me to piece together what I have to do. After about 16 hours of studying, I am at wit's end.

It seems like I can't use SSO, and I also can't use PKCE because there is no working example anywhere on the web. There is a github repo with an example implementation, but it does not function and after 2 hours playing with it I cannot determine what I need to do to move forward this way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `offline_access` to your scope (e.g. "scope": "offline_access openid something:else",) and this will yield you a `refresh_token`.

Auth0 currently supports unlimited `refresh_token` usage, so when your `access_token` expires (you either can track expiration time manually using `"expires_in": 86400` value in respones or react on 401 response from api) - you can send your refresh token to OAuth2 api endpoint and receive new access token back. They have few [descent articles](https://auth0.com/docs/search?q=Refresh%20token) about this matter and what you need to configure for your clients and API as well as what not to do (depending on your client security assumptions).

Take a note - you must secure refresh_token properly - store it in some reliable store and prevent any external scripts from accessing it. I assume with electron app you can do it more reliable than with a public website.